# equivalent of newtype deriving in ScalaZ

Tags: scala, haskell, scalaz

Is there an equivalent of Haskell's `newtype .... deriving` feature ( as described [in this video lecture](http://youtu.be/UBVcV3LIBeU) in the 36th minute ) in ScalaZ ?

[image]

Comment: You can get something similar to the `deriving` part with Shapeless's `Generic` and `Typeclass` type class.

Answer (score 1):

[shapeless-contrib](https://github.com/typelevel/shapeless-contrib#derive-type-classes) allows something similar.